# which.min within reshape2's dcast()?

Tags: r, plyr, reshape, reshape2

I would like to extract the value of var2 that corresponds to the minimum value of var1 in each building-month combination.  Here's my (fake) data set:

```
 head(mydata)

 #  building month      var1     var2
 #1        A     1 -26.96333 376.9633
 #2        A     1 165.38759 317.3993
 #3        A     1  47.46345 271.0137
 #4        A     2  73.47784 294.8171
 #5        A     2 107.80130 371.7668
 #6        A     2  10.16384 308.7975
```

Reproducible code:

```
## create fake data set:
set.seed(142)
mydata1 = data.frame(building = rep(LETTERS[1:5],6),month = sort(rep(1:6,5)),var1=rnorm(30,50,35),var2 = runif(30,200,400))
mydata2 = data.frame(building = rep(LETTERS[1:5],6),month = sort(rep(1:6,5)),var1=rnorm(30,60,35),var2 = runif(30,150,400))
mydata3 = data.frame(building = rep(LETTERS[1:5],6),month = sort(rep(1:6,5)),var1=rnorm(30,40,35),var2 = runif(30,250,400))
mydata = rbind(mydata1,mydata2,mydata3)
mydata = mydata[ order(mydata[,"building"], mydata[,"month"]), ]
row.names(mydata) = 1:nrow(mydata)

## here is how I pull the minimum value of v1 for each building-month combination:
require(reshape2)
m1 = melt(mydata, id.var=1:2)
d1 = dcast(m1, building ~ month, function(x) min(max(x,0), na.rm=T),
           subset = .(variable == "var1"))
```

This pulls out the minimum value of var1 for each building-month combo...

```
head(d1)

#  building         1         2        3         4         5         6
#1        A 165.38759 107.80130 93.32816  73.23279  98.55546 107.58780
#2        B  92.08704  98.94959 57.79610  94.10530  80.86883  99.75983
#3        C  93.38284 100.13564 52.26178  62.37837  91.98839  97.44797
#4        D  82.43440  72.43868 66.83636 105.46263 133.02281  94.56457
#5        E  70.09756  61.44406 30.78444  68.24334  94.35605  61.60610
```

However, what I want is a data frame set up exactly as d1 that instead shows the value of var2 that corresponds to the minimum value pulled for `var1` (shown in `d1` above).  My gut tells me it should be a variation on `which.min()`, but haven't gotten this to work with `dcast()` or `ddply()`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible in one step, but I'm more familiar with plyr than reshape2,

```
dcast(ddply(mydata, .(building, month), summarize, value = var2[which.min(var1)]), 
      building ~ month)
```

Comment: Why do you need `dcast` here?

Comment: to reshape from long to wide

Comment: okay. it's not obvious to me that that's required by the question.

Comment: the last paragraph strongly suggests that it is?

Comment: `plyr`/`ddply` is fine; however, I'm getting an error when I call your code: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'var2' not found`

Comment: oops, sorry I was working on `mydata` directly (skipped the melting step)