# How to use reshape2's dcast to select only one of several observations(values)

Tags: r, date, reshape2, dcast

I have the following dataset

```
> dataset2
   ID ATCcode       date
1   1   N06AA 2001-01-01
2   1   N06AB 2001-04-01
3   1   N06AB 2001-03-01
4   1   N06AB 2001-02-01
5   1   N06AC 2001-01-01
6   2   N06AA 2001-01-01
7   2   N06AA 2001-02-01
8   2   N06AA 2001-03-01
9   3   N06AB 2001-01-01
10  4   N06AA 2001-02-01
11  4   N06AB 2001-03-01
```

It's in long format and I'd like it to be in wide format. However, I only want the earliest date for each ATCcode - and not any of the later dates. Thus I'd like to end up here:

```
> datasetLong
  ID      N06AA      N06AB      N06AC
1  1 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-01-01
2  2 2001-01-01       <NA>       <NA>
3  3       <NA> 2001-01-01       <NA>
4  4 2001-02-01 2001-03-01       <NA>
```

(This is just a sample of the real dataset, it has more variation in the values and more observations than this).

I've managed to cast the dataset somewhat, but not in  the manner which I want to:

```
dataset3 <- reshape2::dcast(dataset2, ID ~ ATCcode)
```

gives me the length of each vector/list:

```
> dataset3
  ID N06AA N06AB N06AC
1  1     1     3     1
2  2     3     0     0
3  3     0     1     0
4  4     1     1     0
```

Instead of the length, I'd like just one value, and that value should be the smallest value (or, the earliest date).

I've found a similar question asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464544/which-min-within-reshape2s-dcast), but I was unable to use that in any way without getting various errors. I have not used melt in the above attempt, is that maybe necessary?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for `reshape2` answer? `reshape2` is [retired](https://github.com/hadley/reshape), The author suggests to use `tidyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses `tidyverse` methods.

One way would be would be to select minimum date from each `ID` and `ATCcode` and convert the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID, ATCcode) %>%
  slice(which.min(date)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = ATCcode, values_from = date)

#     ID N06AA      N06AB      N06AC     
#  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>    
#1     1 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-01-01
#2     2 2001-01-01 NA         NA        
#3     3 NA         2001-01-01 NA        
#4     4 2001-02-01 2001-03-01 NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L), ATCcode = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("N06AA", "N06AB", "N06AC"), class = "factor"), 
date = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("2001-01-01", "2001-02-01", "2001-03-01", 
"2001-04-01"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do.